# Focus style sticking to button with ng-click directive

Tags: css, angularjs, focus, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

I have a problem with my buttons staying focused even after I've clicked on them in my angular app. We are running angular 1.2 with angular-ui-router 0.2. The problem seems to occur both on buttons with the "ng-click"-directive and links with "ui-sref". Here are two screenshots illustrating the problem:

[image: Before click]

The button with the arrow to the right of the search-button simply looks like this:

```
<button class="button-primary" ng-click="toggleSearch()"></button>
```

Now when I click it, it expands the rest of the searchoptions, but the button :focus state stays on the button, like so (don't mind the swedish):

[image]

This happens to pretty much every button within the app, and I can't figure out why. I can of course remove the style altogether:

```
.button-secondary:not([ng-click]):focus {
    //Style here.
}
```

But that's just covering up the problem, not fixing it. I've tried googling all sorts of things, but to no avail. Any ideas of what causes this behaviour and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Isn't that default behaviour for a button? to stay focused once clicked until you click away?

Comment: I guess so, but usually you dont notice it because some other event happens (url-change, submit or something). 

In any case it feels buggy since things actually happen on the screen and the focus should not be on the button anymore. Do I have to manually unfocus it maybe?

Comment: Yes, you have to unfocus it via a custom directive. It should be pretty straight forward.